# Compiling PHP extension - how to get rid of "putwchar() inconsistent dll linkage" warning

Tags: php, c, visual-studio, php-extension, stdio

I'm trying to create a PHP extension for Windows, using the Visual Studio Express. I started the extension from scratch and had just `test.cpp` file, where I wrote some code. Although the code compiled and worked well, during compilation it produced several warnings, I'd rather get rid of.

I reduced the file to a single line, which reproduces those warnings:

```
#include "php.h"
```

Building such an empty DLL I get:

```
>Compiling...
>test.cpp
>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\stdio.h(620) : warning C4273: 'getwchar' : inconsistent dll linkage
>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\stdio.h(435) : see previous definition of 'getwchar'
>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\stdio.h(622) : warning C4273: 'putwchar' : inconsistent dll linkage
>        C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\stdio.h(437) : see previous definition of 'putwchar'
```

**What is the proper way to fix these two warnings?**

I've tried to investigate the issue, and checked if I forgot some preprocessor directive. But I couldn't find anything applicable to influence that `stdio.h` properly.

Here is the list of my preprocessor directives, as set up in the project configuration:

```
WIN32
NDEBUG
_WINDOWS
_USRDLL
TEST_EXPORTS
PHP_WIN32
ZEND_WIN32
ZTS=1
ZEND_DEBUG=0

Inherited values:
_WINDLL
_UNICODE
UNICODE
```

It looks pretty same as other PHP projects have. I've also studied the `stdio.h`, but haven't found appropriate preprocessor directives to set.

So, the main question is divided into smaller questions:

1. What is the PHP authors' intent - should I have those
   `getwchar()` and `putwchar()` functions imported or declared inline? `stdio.h` tries to do that simultaneously.
2. Have I missed some preprocessor directive to set?
3. Do I have to include some win32-specific header files from PHP sources?

Comment: Try adding the `/P` option ("Preprocessor/Preprocess to a File" IDE project option) then search for `getwchar` in the `filename.s` file created by the build.  That should give you an indication of what is different between the declaration and the `inline` definition that is causing the problem.  Once we know that, there's a decent chance we can figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Also, it might help to post the build log file (do not paste from the Build Output IDE window - for some reason the Build Output window filters out important information, like the actual command lines used).

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelBurr - that didn't help much, however at last I found the reason

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eventually I managed to find the issue - that was the **.cpp** extension, which caused the file to be compiled as C++, while the PHP is written in plain C.

The simplest solution is just to rename file to have **.c** extension. And, of course, write the source in C.

Comment: "program it in C" is not a solution, is it?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it adding math.h and wchar.h
see https://jojokahanding.wordpress.com/tag/php-extension/ for a better explanation